# incrementing values of a list at specific indexes python

Tags: python, list, indexing

I am attempting to create a list for each nucleotide (A, G, C, T) in a sequence where the index of the list corresponds to the position in the sequence and the value is the frequency of that nucleotide across all sequences, here are 4 sequences as an example:

```
>ignore this
GTAGGGCGA
>ignore this
GTATACAGC
>ignore this
GTTTCTCTT
>ignore this
GTAATCAAA
```

The code I've written:

```
def function(filename, length):
    g,t,c,a = [],[],[],[]
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            if line.startswith('GT'):
                 gcount, acount, tcount, ccount = 0, 0, 0, 0
                 g = [gcount + 1 if nuc == 'G' else gcount for nuc in line[:length]]
                 return g
```

Right now, this code just looks at the G nucleotides and I get a list for every sequence instead of 1 list that sums the values at each index of the list.

```
[1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

What I would like as my output for g alone:

```
[4, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `numpy` for this. Just convert your lists to `numpy` arrays and add.

```
import numpy as np

list1 = np.array([1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0])
list2 = np.array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0])
list3 = np.array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
list4 = np.array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])

list1 + list2 + list3 +list4 # desired result!
>>> array([4, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0])
```

Here's how you can modify your current function to support this:

```
def function(filename, length)
    g,t,c,a = [],[],[],[]
    # create an array of expected length of g filled with 0s
    base = np.zeros((1,length)) # 1 row, `length` number of columns
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            if line.startswith('GT'):
                gcount, acount, tcount, ccount = 0, 0, 0, 0
                g = np.array([gcount + 1 if nuc == 'G' else gcount for nuc in line[:length]])
                base = base + g # add this new numpy array
    return base # return the summed result
```

Here are installation instruction for [`numpy`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/install.html).

Comment: I have been interested in what numpy is and how it could apply to my code. Thank you! However, this example only shows 4 sequences, there could be thousands of sequences in the file. Could I modify this code to account for this?

Comment: @Ouwan Of course. In fact, I already provided you such an implementation by modifying your `function` function.

Comment: when I switch the file I'm testing from these example to sequences of different length, I am getting ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1,9) (5,) ?

Comment: @Ouwan12: I assumed that all of your vectors will have the same length, and chose the initial length that seemed best suited for your solution. You'll need to play around with the definition of `base` so that it'll always start off with the length that all of your future arrays will also have. In this regard, you know best - I don't know the rest of your code, sadly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
g = [sum(_) for _ in zip(*[[1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])]
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a little easier to understand. Note that it will eventually fail if your input file is too large:

```
import collections

Test_data = """>ignore this
GTAGGGCGA
>ignore this
GTATACAGC
>ignore this
GTTTCTCTT
>ignore this
GTAATCAAA
"""


import io
testfh = io.StringIO(Test_data)

counts = [collections.Counter(fil) for fil in zip(*(x.strip() for x in testfh if not x.startswith('>')))]

for key in 'ACGT':
    key_counts = [cnt[key] for cnt in counts]
    print("{}: {}".format(key, key_counts))
```

Output looks like this:

```
A: [0, 0, 3, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2]
C: [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1]
G: [4, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0]
T: [0, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]
```

**EDIT**

Without comprehensions:

```
counts = [collections.Counter(fil) for fil in zip(*(x.strip() for x in testfh if not x.startswith('>')))]
```

Turns into this:

```
clean_lines = []
for x in testfh:
    if not x.startswith('>'):
        clean_lines.append(x.strip())
```

At this point, `clean_lines` contains just the good parts, with no newlines:

```
GTAGGGCGA
GTATACAGC
GTTTCTCTT
GTAATCAAA
```

Next I turn them sideways, in order to feed the vertical stripes to `Counter`:

```
file_and_rank = zip(*clean_lines)
```

In that line, `*clean_lines` takes each of the lines (which is a string) and flattens them out into a big parameter list, as if I had called:

```
file_and_rank = zip('GTAGGGCGA', 'GTATACAGC', 'GTTTCTCTT', 'GTAATCAAA', ...)
```

The `zip` operation combines together iterables. It loops over all of them at the same time, taking one value off each iterable. It then puts all the values together into a tuple, and returns that. Thus, it converts the GTAGGGCGA, ... strings into tuples with the first, second, third, etc. character of each string:

```
    (GGGG)
    (TTTT)
    (AATA)
    (GTTA)
    ...
```

Next, I need to build a count of how many nucleotides were in each position. So I'll use `collections.Counter` (which wants an iterable!) but I have to have a separate one for each position. So a list of them:

```
counts = []
for fil in file_and_rank:
    counts.append(collections.Counter(fil))
```

I'm just taking a tuple, like (AATA) and passing it to the constructor for `collections.Counter`. That will produce a Counter with `{A:3, T:1}` for that position.

Comment: This is very nice. What exactly is "fil"? Also, I am a student trying to learn, would you mind showing me how the counts line is without list comprehension? Thank you!

Comment: I used `fil` because `file` is reserved and likely to be confusing. Basically, it's a vertical slice down the input ([see "rank" and "file"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_and_file)). Without comprehensions, that is going to be enormous.

Answer (score 0):

Like Austin, I recommend using a Counter from the collections module.  It's built for this kind of task.  Here's my variation: keep a Counter for each nucleotide and feed the counter the positions at which each nucleotide occurs.  It processes one line at a time like your original code.

```
from collections import Counter

def function(filename, length):
    # a counter for each nucleotide
    count = {'G':Counter(),
             'T':Counter(),
             'C':Counter(),
             'A':Counter()
             }

    max_length = 0

    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            if line.startswith('GT'):
                for position, nuc in enumerate(line):
                    # update position count for the nucleotides in this line
                    count[nuc].update([position])  

                # keep track of longest line 
                max_length = max(max_length, position)

    g = [[count[nuc][i] for i in range(max_length)] for nuc in 'GTCA']

    return g
```

Comment: Hmmm I'm receiving the following error:
    File "monkey.py", line 31, in <module>
        function('introntest.txt', 9)
      File "monkey.py", line 25, in function
        count[nuc].update(position)
      File "C:\Users\Leddy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-    32\lib\collections\__init__.py", line 601, in update
    _count_elements(self, iterable)
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: My bad.  That line should read `count[nuc].update([position])`.  Fixed the answer.